# Automatically override default Google custom search style

Tags: css, google-custom-search

I am setting up completely custom styling for Google Custom Search to match the rest of my website. I downloaded the complete CSS for the elements ([here](https://cse.google.com/cse/style/look/espresso.css)) and am modifying that. However, some of it ends overridden by the default custom search styles here: http://www.google.com/uds/api/search/1.0/56f70d816baa48bdfe9284ebc883ad41/default+en.css

Is there any way I can force my styles to take precedence (without having to put in `!important` on nearly every line) or prevent the search elements from even using the default+en.css styles at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an inline stylesheet or inline styles, possibly you might need `!important` but it could at least be limited to the elements/main block you are using it in, which would allow multiple search engines per page with different css for each.

An alternative is that google suggests you use the *version 1* code for 'advanced settings'(!) - in the page you get the code from this is the tiny link at the very bottom of the page. It displays this code which has  inline styles (replace XXXX and YYY with the IDs needed for your search engine:

```
<div id='cse' style='width: 100%;'>Loading</div>
<script src='//www.google.com/jsapi' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>google.load('search', '1', {language: 'en', style: google.loader.themes.V2_DEFAULT});
google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
var customSearchOptions = {};
var orderByOptions = {};
orderByOptions['keys'] = [{label: 'Relevance', key: ''} , {label: 'Date', key: 'date'}];
customSearchOptions['enableOrderBy'] = true;
customSearchOptions['orderByOptions'] = orderByOptions;
var imageSearchOptions = {};
imageSearchOptions['layout'] = 'google.search.ImageSearch.LAYOUT_POPUP';
customSearchOptions['enableImageSearch'] = true;
customSearchOptions['overlayResults'] = true;
var customSearchControl =   new google.search.CustomSearchControl('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:YYYYYYYYY', customSearchOptions);

  customSearchControl.setResultSetSize(google.search.Search.FILTERED_CSE_RESULTSET);
var options = new google.search.DrawOptions();
options.setAutoComplete(true);
customSearchControl.draw('cse', options);
}, true);
</script>
<style type='text/css'>
.gsc-control-cse {
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
border-color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.gsc-control-cse .gsc-table-result {
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
input.gsc-input, .gsc-input-box, .gsc-input-box-hover, .gsc-input-box-focus {
border-color: #D9D9D9;
}
input.gsc-search-button, input.gsc-search-button:hover, input.gsc-search-button:focus {
border-color: #333333;
background-color: #333333;
background-image: none;
filter: none;
}
.gsc-tabHeader.gsc-tabhInactive {
border-color: #FF9900;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.gsc-tabHeader.gsc-tabhActive {
border-color: #E9E9E9;
background-color: #E9E9E9;
border-bottom-color: #FF9900
}
.gsc-tabsArea {
border-color: #FF9900;
}
.gsc-webResult.gsc-result, .gsc-results .gsc-imageResult {
border-color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.gsc-webResult.gsc-result:hover, .gsc-imageResult:hover {
border-color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
.gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:link, .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:link b, .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:link, .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:link b  {
 color: #0000CC;
}
.gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:visited, .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:visited b, .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:visited, .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:visited b {
color: #0000CC;
}
.gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:hover, .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:hover b, .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:hover, .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:hover b {
color: #0000CC;
 }
.gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:active, .gs-webResult.gs-result a.gs-title:active b, .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:active, .gs-imageResult a.gs-title:active b {
color: #0000CC;
 }
 .gsc-cursor-page {
color: #0000CC;
 }
 a.gsc-trailing-more-results:link {
 color: #0000CC;
 }
 .gs-webResult .gs-snippet, .gs-imageResult .gs-snippet, .gs-fileFormatType {
 color: #000000;
  }
 .gs-webResult div.gs-visibleUrl, .gs-imageResult div.gs-visibleUrl {
 color: #008000;
 }
 .gs-webResult div.gs-visibleUrl-short {
 color: #008000;
 }
 .gs-webResult div.gs-visibleUrl-short  {
 display: none;
  }
 .gs-webResult div.gs-visibleUrl-long {
 display: block;
  }
 .gs-promotion div.gs-visibleUrl-short {
 display: none;
 }
 .gs-promotion div.gs-visibleUrl-long  {
 display: block;
 }
 .gsc-cursor-box {
 border-color: #FFFFFF;
 }
 .gsc-results .gsc-cursor-box .gsc-cursor-page {
 border-color: #E9E9E9;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 color: #0000CC;
 }
 .gsc-results .gsc-cursor-box .gsc-cursor-current-page {
 border-color: #FF9900;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 color: #0000CC;
 }
 .gsc-webResult.gsc-result.gsc-promotion {
 border-color: #336699;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 }
 .gsc-completion-title {
 color: #0000CC;
 }
 .gsc-completion-snippet {
 color: #000000;
 }
 .gs-promotion a.gs-title:link,.gs-promotion a.gs-title:link *,.gs-promotion .gs-snippet a:link  {
 color: #0000CC;
 }
 .gs-promotion a.gs-title:visited,.gs-promotion a.gs-title:visited *,.gs-promotion .gs-snippet a:visited {
 color: #0000CC;
 }
 .gs-promotion a.gs-title:hover,.gs-promotion a.gs-title:hover *,.gs-promotion .gs-snippet a:hover  {
 color: #0000CC;
 }
 .gs-promotion a.gs-title:active,.gs-promotion a.gs-title:active *,.gs-promotion .gs-snippet a:active {
 color: #0000CC;
 }
 .gs-promotion .gs-snippet, .gs-promotion .gs-title .gs-promotion-title-right, .gs-promotion .gs-title .gs-promotion-title-right * {
 color: #000000;
 }
 .gs-promotion .gs-visibleUrl,.gs-promotion .gs-visibleUrl-short  {
 color: #008000;
 }
 </style>
```

**Second option**

Add an id to the HTML and style using the `#id` since this should take precedence over the class which google uses in its styling. The id only need be a parent rather than on each element, css could then apply to whenever the `id` is followed by the `class` you want, or whenever the `class` is a child of the `id`, eg in the form:

```
#my-cse1 .cse .gsc-input { } 
#my-cse1 > .gsc-input { }
```